# Continuous push message giving BadRequest from Azure

Tags: c#, push-notification

My service is register with azzure notification hub. And using my .net server API it push notification to particular device within particular time frame.
Everything goes right except when I try to send multiple push in same code it stuck with "BadRequest" except first one.

Below is the code

```
public static async void SendAzzurePushNotification()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        HttpStatusCode pushNotificationStatus = await CreateAndPushAsync("user_37");
        Console.WriteLine(pushNotificationStatus);
    }
}

static async Task<HttpStatusCode> CreateAndPushAsync(string tag)
{
    HttpStatusCode pushNotificationStatus = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        string uri = "<HUBURI>";

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", <SASTOKEN>);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "gcm");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", tag);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-01");

        response = await client.PostAsync(uri,
                new StringContent("{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        pushNotificationStatus = response.StatusCode;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return pushNotificationStatus;
}
```

Above code give me Created status for first time and then BadRequest after that. If same api I call from client like postman. It work fine.

I also tried nuget package from azure notification hub, regarding which code is as below. Which solve my above issue but it won't return me any status code which I can have in my above code for success.

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<CONNECTIONSTRING>", "<HUB>");
NotificationOutcome outcome = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}", "user_37");
```

Comment: did u used `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs` before? bcoz it does not require to give all of stuff you did with `client`, with above package you can able to send multiple notification

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: do you want status code from hub right?

Comment: Not exactly, Actually I need some mechanism using which I can find that device receive that notification or not. But yes even if I get status from azure it is fine for now.

Comment: so here i add the answer try this

Answer (score 0):

Call `send` method with your `tags` and your `notification-data`

```
private static readonly string Endpoint = @"Your End Point";
private static readonly string HubName = @"You Hub Name";
private static NotificationHubClient Hub { get { return NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(Endpoint, HubName); } }

public static async Task Send(string[] tags, object data)
{
    try
   {

        string payload = string.Empty;
        string json_gcm = string.Empty;

        if (data.GetType() != typeof(string))
        {
            //If your notification data is of type
            payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            json_gcm = "{ \"data\" : " + payload + "}";
        }
        else
        {
            //If your notification data is simply is in string
            payload = Convert.ToString(data);
            json_gcm = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + payload + "\"}}";
        }


        // Android
        NotificationOutcome gcmOutcome = null;
        gcmOutcome = await Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(json_gcm, tags);

        if (gcmOutcome != null)
        {
            if (!((gcmOutcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Abandoned) || (gcmOutcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Unknown)))
            {
                //Do code when notification successfully send to Android
             }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Do code when any exception occurred while sending notification  


    } 
}
```

**NotificationOutcomeState:** Gives you status code in the form of enum that represent your notification has been successfully sent or not.

You may ignore if-else block as your need.

Try once may it help you